# Query between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a query between 2 tables that allow me know the total per `SKUs`.

Table 1: order_item

```
order_item_id(pk)    order_id    product_id    qty_ordered    total
```

Table 2:product

```
product_id       SKU    name    price
```

I've tried the following:

```
from product
select SKU
Natural Join order_item
```

Comment: `SELECT P.SKU, SUM(Total) Total FROM Product P INNER JOIN Order_Item OT ON P.Product_Id = OT.Product_Id GROUP BY P.SKU`?

Comment: @Sami missing group by

Comment: Tip of today: forget about the NATURAL JOIN construction. Do a regular JOIN with ON clause where you explicitly specify the join conditions!

Comment: Natural join is not even supported by SQL Server.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=T-SQL+Toturial&rlz=1C1LENP_iwIL718IL718&oq=T-SQL+Toturial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6598j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(qty_ordered), p.name, p.SKU 
FROM   product p 
       JOIN order_item o 
         ON p.product_id    = o.product_id    
group by 
       p.name, p.SKU
```

Useful link on aggregates and grouping: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp